# Heroku error: One CLI for webpack must be installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpacker

I'm trying to deploy my ruby on rails app to heroku but I get the following errors: [heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJLnG.png). I'm working on Rails 6.0.5.1 and I was able to deploy the app perfectly before, so I don't know what could be wrong. Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "proyecto",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@activeadmin/activeadmin": "^2.13.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.2.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.20.0"
  }
}
```

I have already tried the following solution I found online: heroku config:set YARN_PRODUCTION=true , but it just creates a run time error because it never stops compiling. I also tried to reinstall webpack-cli but it didn´t solve the problem. At this point I'm not sure if this is the error causing the app to crash or if it's the one that it's after it :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json
```

:
I also tried to fix that problem comenting the line

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

and the main page charges, but the dropdowns aren't working so It's not a viable solution. Also tried to set

```
 extract_css: true
```

to false, and it doesn't change anything. I feel like I have tried every solution online and none of it works for me

Comment: Have you tried `yarn add webpack-cli`

Comment: Yes, I did and nothing changed